# Can I delete file in Nifi after send messages to kafka?

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I'm using nifi as an ETL tool.

[Process IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5IW1.png)

This is my current process. I use TailFile to detect CSV file and then send messages to Kafka.

It works fine so far, but i want to delete CSV file after i send contents of csv to Kafka.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on why you are using TailFile. From the docs,

```
"Tails" a file, or a list of files, ingesting data from the file as it is written to the file
```

[TailFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/) is used to get new lines that are added to the same file, as they are written. If you need to a tail a file that is being written to, what condition determines it is no longer being written to?

However, if you are just consuming complete files from the local file system, then you could use [GetFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/) which gives the option to delete the file after it is consumed.

From a remote file system, you could use [ListSFTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/) and [FetchSFTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP/) which has a Completion Strategy to move or delete.